# querystring picking up last row in table and not specified row. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, postback, query-string, response.redirect

i have created a table with 2 fields in vb.net as follows -

```
            Do While SqlDR.Read()
                TR = New HtmlTableRow

                TD = New HtmlTableCell
                TD.InnerHtml = SqlDR("name")
                TR.Cells.Add(TD)

                TB.Rows.Add(TR)
            Loop
        SqlDR.Close()
```

Data looks like this -

```
Name 
Jimi
Jonathan
Paulie
```

How do i put a hyperlink on the name cell, so when i click on a specific name it will goto next page with that name?

Comment: If you're looping through a datareader by hand to create html in asp.net, you're doing something horribly wrong.  Are you open to a solution using databinding instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `<asp:HyperLink>` to be your hyperlink, but it tends to be bad form to use hyperlinks as post backs.

You should probably use the LinkButton's CommandName and CommandArgument properties. Where the command name is whatever you want and command argument is the id for that particular row.

Then you can create a Command event handler to redirect to the appropriate page.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname.aspx

Or you could just make the NavigateURL of the hyperlink just be:

```
NavigateURL = "profiles.aspx?name_id=" & l.ID
```

Comment: i just want to remove the link button and give normal hyperlink. is that possible in vb.net? like u do in html with href ?

Answer (score 0):

This backwards from how asp.net is supposed to work.  You want to re-think *everything* and do something more like this in your markup instead:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource Id="somedatasource" runat="serveR" ConnectionString="..." SelectCommand="..." />

<table><tr><th>Names</th></tr>
<asp:Repeater id="somerepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="somedatasource">
    <ItemTemplate><tr><td><a href="page?name=Eval("name")">Eval("name")</a></td></tr></ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```